# FBSDKShareDialog iOS 9 without Fb app

Tags: ios, facebook-graph-api, ios9, facebook-opengraph

I want to allow users without FB app to share open graph - to call share dialog. (With FB app, all working perfect). Is that possible on iOS9? Here is the code (i made content and all):

```
        FBSDKShareDialog *shareDialog = [[FBSDKShareDialog alloc] init];
        shareDialog.fromViewController = self;
        shareDialog.shareContent = content;
        shareDialog.delegate = self;
        [shareDialog show];
        if (![shareDialog canShow]) {
            // update the app UI accordingly
        }
        NSError *error;
        if (![shareDialog validateWithError:&error]) {
            // check the error for explanation of invalid content
        }
```

And here what i get when i try to share without FB app (app is not crashing, nothing happen):

```
 -canOpenURL: failed for URL: "fbauth2:/" - error: "(null)"
```

Before sharing in the app, user can login successfully in fb with Safari..
Thanks.

Comment: If there is no app, it will ask the user to install the app. What do you want to achieve? There is no way to share it without calling the FB app if you are using FBSDK

Comment: i want to share FBSDKShareOpenGraphAction. it would be nice at last to ask user to install app, but nothing is happen..